# Как скрыть и показать HTML элементов с помощью flask

Tags: python, flask

Как скрыть и показать HTML элементов с помощью flask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Через flask нельзя, но можно через jinja вот ссылка https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#if